# Passing down props in a React library invisible to the app using the library

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, redux

I am developing an open source library to use the [Ionic framework](http://ionicframework.com/) with React (it normally works with Angular): https://github.com/pors/reactionic/

This React-Ionic library can be used by developers to create mobile apps. These apps will have their own way to keep state in their app, either by passing down props through composition, or using Flux/Redux, etc.

The React-Ionic library also needs to keep state for a number of things. For example, the "Body" component that wraps all contents needs to know if the content contains "Tabs". So the "Tabs" component needs to be able to change the state in a higher-up component.

I currently use composition to do this, but this has the disadvantage that the app developer needs to pass on props that are specific to the React-Ionic library. I want these props to be invisible for the developer.

What is the "*React way*" of solving this? I can think of two things, please let me know what the best solution is:

- Use [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).
- Use Flex/Redux just for the library. Is this possible? Won't it interfere with the "state management" used by the app?
- Otherwise?

I have added an image that hopefully clarifies what I try to accomplish:

[image]

So I want to pass state information down from the IonBody component to the IonTabs component, without the "App component" having to pass props down. And similarly, the IonTabs component should be able to call an IonBody function.

Thanks!

Comment: It's Flux, not Flex :)

Comment: @markthethomas haha, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

1) If you want to pass props down so they "fall through" to a child component, you can use the JSX spread operator, which will merge in old props:

```
<Component {...this.props} more="values" />
```

2) Context is an experimental feature and shouldn't be used unless in a very specific few cases; it essentially lets you create a "falling leaf" outside the state tree you create w/ props. This can lead to very unexpected results since it is generally outside the React/Flux paradigms. There **are** a few use cases for it, but they're generally only as last-resorts or only with very specific rationale

3) With one-way data flow, you generally want to use something like Flux/Redux **for** your state management. Child components don't get to really know about their parents, and vice versa. They communicate via props (and only top-down, really), so actions need to go "back to the top" of the state tree and propagate down from there.

As a last note, I wonder if you might consider [React-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) over React-ionic. It's going places IMO and is probably the ideal choice for taking a React app native. Just a thought :)

Comment: Thanks for your response, very valid points. I already make use of the spread operator BTW. The thing is: this is a library, I don't want users of the library have to think about the internals of it, that includes passing through props with a spread operator. React-router uses context for this reason (I think), but many people frown on using context which is why I asked this question here. 3) Using Flux/Redux: can there be two instances in a single app (library and the app itself?)

Comment: And yes, React-native is awesome, but there is plenty of demand for Ionic with React (or Angular of course). There's many Meteoric apps out there e.g. that people want to port from Blaze to React.